# Winsock non-blocking overlapped IO still blocks

Tags: sockets, network-programming, winsock2

I am trying to write a simple [winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673(v=vs.85).aspx) client that sends data to a 
winsock server using **non-blocking** **overlapped** IO. The problem is that the `WSASend` call is blocking. The client code looks like this

```
// Initialize Winsock
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ConnectSocket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);

// Connect to server.
WSAConnect(ConnectSocket, ai_addr, ai_addrlen, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// Make the socket non-blocking
u_long iMode = 1;
ioctlsocket(ConnectSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);

// Send the data
WSAOVERLAPPED SendOverlapped{};
SendOverlapped.hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
WSASend(ConnectSocket, &DataBuf, 1, &SendBytes, 0, &SendOverlapped, 0);
```

I have made the socket non-blocking through the `ioctlsocket` function and I have provided `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag to the `WSASocket` function. I have also provided the `lpOverlapped` parameter to the `WSASend` function. However, the call to `WSASend` is still blocking. Am I missing something here?

Please excuse the lack of error checking in the above code, it is only to keep it simple for the purposes of this question.

**Clarification**: The reason why it seems to me the call is blocking is this - I called the `WSASend` function 2560 times in a loop, sending 4MB each time in the loop. The loop completed in 16 secs after all the data was transferred to the server. If it was non-blocking, I would have expected the loop to complete much sooner. As expected, the `WSASend` function does return with `ERROR_IO_PENDING` though.

Here is the full client code

```
// Client.cpp
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 4 * 1024 * 1024
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    // Resolve the server address and port
    addrinfo *result = NULL;
    addrinfo hints{};
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = WSAConnect(ConnectSocket, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Make the socket non-blocking
    u_long iMode = 1;
    iResult = ioctlsocket(ConnectSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        printf("ioctlsocket failed with error: %ld\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare the buffer
    char *sendbuf = new char[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_BUFLEN; ++i)
        sendbuf[i] = 'a';
    WSABUF DataBuf;
    DWORD SendBytes = 0;
    DataBuf.buf = sendbuf;
    DataBuf.len = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Send the buffer in a loop
    int loopCount = 2560;
    WSAOVERLAPPED* SendOverlapped = (WSAOVERLAPPED*)calloc(loopCount, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPED));
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; ++i)
    {
        SendOverlapped[i].hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
        iResult = WSASend(ConnectSocket, &DataBuf, 1, &SendBytes, 0, SendOverlapped + i, 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            if (ERROR_IO_PENDING == WSAGetLastError())
            {
                continue;
            }           

            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "initiating send data took " << clock() - start << " ms" << std::endl;

    // Wait for all the events to be signalled
    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; ++i)
    {
        iResult = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &SendOverlapped[i].hEvent, TRUE, INFINITE, TRUE);
        if (iResult == WSA_WAIT_FAILED) {
            printf("WSAWaitForMultipleEvents failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        DWORD Flags = 0;
        BOOL result = WSAGetOverlappedResult(ConnectSocket, SendOverlapped + i, &SendBytes, FALSE, &Flags);
        if (result == FALSE) {
            printf("WSASend failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "actual send data took " << clock() - start << " ms";

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    ////free(SendOverlapped);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the server side code

```
// Server.cpp
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 4 * 1024 * 1024
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    // Resolve the server address and port
    addrinfo hints{};
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    addrinfo *result = NULL;
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    SOCKET ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket);

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    char* recvbuf = new char[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    do {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else  {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean that the "call is blocking"?  Even if you specify that overlapped IO should be used, the API might be able to complete the call before returning.  As the docs say, "If an overlapped operation completes immediately, WSASend returns a value of zero and the lpNumberOfBytesSent parameter is updated with the number of bytes sent".

Comment: There is absolutely zero error-checking in this code. You can't write code like this.

Comment: @EJP, I know there is no error checking, and that is only to keep this question neat.

Comment: The reason I say the call is blocking is because when I run the WSASend function in a loop 256 times, sending 4MB each time, the loop didn't finish till all the data was sent to the server

Comment: Single non-blocking call means: WSASend returns immediately, and you need to wait for overlapped event for actual I/O operation completion. Nothing more than this. You expect too much from asynchronous calls.

Comment: You may think you're 'keeping the question neat', but you're only raising the suspicion that you've ignored any errors that may have occurred, or, worse, not even known about them. In this case you at least need to provide evidence that the ioctlsocket() call succeeded, otherwise your question isn't about anything. And there is no loop in this code. In short, the code you posted doesn't clearly exhibit the problem you describe.

Comment: Can you show the code that loops?

Comment: @EJP, Please give some thought before downvoting a question. If you need more information, you can always ask. It hurts to lose the very few points that one has and discourages asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: I mentioned what was missing, on two separate occasions. But voting here is a secret ballot. You don't know who downvoted this question, and you have no business speculating about it, or asserting without evidence that it was done without prior thought.

Comment: Thanks EJP and everyone for your comments. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Hmm.. 2560*4MB is 10GB of data that has to be copied into the network stack buffers.  I wonder how big they are, and what happens internally if the buffer-space fills up? IMHO, transferring such a large amount of data in a non-blocking fashion is better done with 'real' non-blocking overlapped, eg. IOCP.  IOCP does not require the buffer data to be copied into kernel space.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `WSASend` call was blocking because it was completing too quickly. One would think a 4MB transfer would be sufficiently large to call for async processing but that was not the case. When I inserted a sleep of 1 ms on the server side, I could see the client processing asynchronously, and the loop ended much before the data transfer.

Comment: The WSASend() call wasn't blocking at all. You misinterpreted the symptoms. It was *returning.* The I/O happens asynchronously. You don't seem to understand your own code. See @AlexFarber's comment above.

Comment: If a for loop that runs 2560 times takes 16 secs to complete, to me that is blocking.

Comment: The code behaves much worse on my machine than you describe. The client never completes, and after a second run I couldn't even kill the client process - I ultimately had to reboot my machine.  I suspect that my anti-malware firewall might be causing some problems with this.  Doe anyone else feel like anti-malware causes nearly as much trouble as the malware its supposed to prevent?

Comment: @Michael, you can try reducing the loop count to 256 instead of 2560. I had the same issue you described on another computer.

Comment: @EJP, you can do a test to confirm the call is blocking. Please do your homework before commenting on others understanding of code.